# Bash for loop not writing to file

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, paste, cut

I often work like this:

```
for skra in `ls *txt` ; do paste foo.csv <(cut -f 5 $skra) > foo.csv; done
```

for looping through a directory by using 'ls'

Now I don't understand why this command does not add column to foo.csv in every loop

What is happening under the hood? Seems like foo.csv is not saved in every iteration

The output I get is field 5 from the last file. Not even the original foo.csv as I get if I only `paste foo.csv bar.txt`

EDIT:
All files are tab delimited

foo.csv is just one column in the beginning

example.txt as seen in vim with `set list`:

> (101,6352)(11174,51391)(10000,60000)^INC_044048.1^I35000^I6253^I0.038250$
> (668,7819)(23384,69939)(20000,70000)^INC_044048.1^I45000^I7153^I0.034164$
> (2279,8111)(32691,73588)(30000,80000)^INC_044048.1^I55000^I5834^I0.031908$

Here is a python script that does what I want:

```
import pandas

rammi=[]

with open('window.list') as f:

    for line in f:

        nafn=line.strip()

        df=pandas.read_csv(nafn, header=None, names=[nafn], sep='\t', usecols=[4])

        rammi.append(df)

frame = pandas.concat(rammi, axis=1)

frame.to_csv('rammi.allra', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Paste column 4 from all files to one (initially I wanted to retain one original column but it was not necessary). The question was about bash not wanting to update stdin in the for loop.

Comment: Redirecting `stdout` to the file you're taking input from sounds like a very bad idea...

Comment: You'll need to provide a sample of you CSVs that seff-explains their format: What delimiter do they use? Does `"` ever appear in them? Can the fields contain newlines in them? **And** the expected output from your sample input files. BTW, CSVs are basic text files so you can edit/see them with a text editor

Comment: by default, `cut` and `paste` use TAB-delimited fields, so what you're trying to do doesn't make much sense if your CSV is COMMA-delimited

Comment: True stdout as stdin sounds bad. Nonetheless, why isn't the stdin updated between iterations?

Comment: Side note: [Do not parse output from `ls`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) The answer to your question is that (other mistakes aside) redirecting into `foo.csv` truncates the file to begin with, so reading from that same file produces either empty input or undefined behavior, depending on which shell you use.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek seems like you have the answer. The reading from file produces empty input depending on which shell you use....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, opening `foo.csv` for output will truncate it in most shells. (Even if that was not the case, opening the file and running `cut` and `paste` repeatedly looks quite inefficient.)

If you don’t mind keeping all the data in memory at one point in time, a simple AWK or Bash script can do this type of processing without any further processes such as `cut` or `paste`.

```bash
awk -F'\t' '    { lines[FNR] = lines[FNR] "\t" $5 }
            END { for (l in lines) print substr(lines[l], 2) }' \
    *.txt > foo.csv
```

(The output should not be called `.csv`, but I’m sticking with the naming from the question nonetheless.)

Actually, one doesn’t really need `awk` for this, Bash will do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
lines=()
for file in *.txt; do
  declare -i i=0
  while IFS=$'\t' read -ra line; do
    lines[i++]+=$'\t'"${line[4]}"
  done < "$file"
done
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]/#?}" > foo.csv
```

(As a side note, `"${lines[@]:1}"` would remove the first line, not the first (`\t`) character of each line. (This particular expansion syntax works differently for strings (scalars) and arrays in Bash.) Hence `"${lines[@]/#?}"` (another way to express the removal of the first character), which does get applied to each array element.)

Comment: You don't need to refer to an index to append to an array. `lines+=( "new content" )` suffices; so the `i` variable can be discarded entirely.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I’m not appending to an array here. I’m appending to a particular element of the array. So the `i` is needed. (Similarly, the `l` and `FNR` in `awk` are needed.)

Comment: Ahh. I was also wondering why append the tabs inside the data instead of the printf string, but now that makes sense.

Comment: so.sh: 2: so.sh: declare: not found
so.sh: 3: read: Illegal option -a
so.sh: 7: so.sh: Bad substitution

Comment: @AWE The question was tagged `bash` and Bash was also explicitly (and repeatedly) mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Well it works now, I was lazy and just wrote `sh`. It shifts all columns to the left (when columns are not as long)